# Apache access.log: unauthorized user able to request files on my localhost dev machine

Tags: security, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I have Apache2.4 installed on my dev PC (windows 10)

Viewing my Apache24\logs\access.log file, I noticed suspect entries such as:

```
www.-----.com - - [01/Jan/2018:10:45:19 -0200] "GET /SOME-PERSONAL-DEV-PROJECT/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21061
www.-----.com - - [02/Jan/2018:07:04:00 -0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/sql.php?server=1&db=-----&table=-----&pos=0&token=ea
www.-----.com - - [02/Jan/2018:07:04:01 -0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/sql.php?server=1&db==-----&&table==-----&&pos=0&token=ea
www.-----.com - - [02/Jan/2018:07:04:08 -0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?ajax_request=1&recent_table=1&token=ea
```

I have 'phpmyadmin' on localhost and also 'SOME-PERSONAL-DEV-PROJECT' is another folder in my localhost for personal web dev stuff.

'www.-----.com' is a known ad network domain and I know they are related to shady stuff.

So in my httpd.conf file I have this config rule:

```
<Directory "c:/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require local
</Directory>
```

From my understanding, "Require local" would prevent anything that is not localhost to be able to make requests to the files in my local machine

So my question is, why is this domain apparently being successful in accessing files from my local dev machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally make Apache listen only on the localhost IP address (127.0.0.1), there is probably a line like this somewhere in your configuration:

```
Listen 80
```

or

```
Listen *:80
```

Change it to

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

And read more in the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) on the subject.

Another possibility of the log messages may be, that your 127.0.0.1 IP address resolves to www.......com, just check your hosts file or try `nslookup 127.0.0.1` or something else to do the reverse DNS search, I'm not a windows user so I may have the command wrong.

If 127.0.0.1 resolved to the name, your own requests would be logged with it.

Comment: Yes, in my Windows' hosts file, I have blocked this ad network domain long ago with a line `127.0.0.1 www.-----.com`. Could this be causing my own accesses to randomly be logged as being from this bad domain?

Comment: @tommbr Yes, if you put that in your hosts file, then that's why it's being logged that way. Those are your own requests.

Answer (score 1):

Those logs are showing your own requests to the web server.

We see from your comment that you said you added `127.0.0.1 www.-----.com` to the Windows hosts file.

Unfortunately, you have Apache configured to do reverse DNS lookups on IP addresses before logging them. Somewhere in your Apache configuration is:

```
HostnameLookups On
```

So, instead of logging `127.0.0.1`, Apache logged `www.-----.com`, because when it did a hostname lookup on 127.0.0.1, that name was provided from the hosts file.

Change this to `Off`, and your logs will begin showing correct IP addresses again.